# User avatar not displayed

Tags: angular, devise

The profile of the user should display his avatar, but in the place of this he showed me something like a broken picture. Avatars are loaded into a separate database table and connected to the user table.

The console displays this error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)

She says the user doesn't have an avatar? If so, all users have their own uploaded avatar. Is there any mistake or need to add something else?

```
<div *ngIf="authTokenService.currentUserData">
  <a>
    <img [src]="authTokenService.currentUserData ? authTokenService.currentUserData.avatar : 'assets/img/default_avatar.png'" name="avatar">                        
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `authTokenService.currentUserData.avatar` is null. Also the check on `authTokenService.currentUserData` in your image tag is obsolete. This is checked in the `*ngIf`

Comment: authTokenService.currentUserData seems to be defined but authTokenService.currentUserData.avatar is not. do you have an initialiser for authTokenService.currentUserData?

Comment: No, but what should I do? (I used an angular2-token), it normally displays the rest of the values only the avatar is not displayed